# zsh broke compose key and special chars

Tags: zsh, locale, keyboard-layout

I thought I'd switch to zsh, so I did just that with `chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh user`, unfortunately, it broke my compose key (unresponsive both in the console and in an X terminal); also, when I read email in emacs rmail, Swedish characters are not displayed correctly (diamonds in the console, question marks in an X terminal) - but it **is** possible to display them, for example if I `cat` the mail files instead.

To possibly reinitialize the compose key, I run `setupcon` again as superuser but it didn't help. In `/etc/default/keyboard`, this line is present `XKBOPTIONS="compose:lwin,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"`.

As for the compose key in X, and the character set in both the console and an X terminal, I'm clueless because I can't remember anytime "setting up" those things, they just worked.

To double check, I switched back to bash with `chsh -s /bin/bash user`, and everything worked as before. I examined `.profile` and `.bashrc` to see if I possibly had done some keyboard/charmap initialization there, but I couldn't find anything to that extent.

```
zsh --version
zsh 4.3.17 (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: Look at .bash_profile vs zprofile and equivalent in /etc, especially about locals (LC_* or LANG variables)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: 100% correct, I put `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` in `/etc/default/locale` and that solved both problems. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Forgot to say, that didn't quite do it in X, had to put `export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` in `.xsessionrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since bash or zsh is in no way responsible for handling the Compose key, what must have broken is your session startup files. Check your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`, or `/etc/profile`, for commands that might have a bearing on the locale setting, such as values for the `LANG` or `LC_CTYPE` environment variables. It's likely that your keyboard configuration no longer matches your application's idea of the system character set.

You can make zsh read your `.profile` by putting the following command in your `~/.zprofile`:

```
emulate -R sh -c '. ~/.profile'
```

If that doesn't suffice (especially under X), tell us what distribution (e.g. Ubuntu, Fedora, …), what desktop environment (or window manager, e.g. KDE4, Gnome2, XFCE4, …) and what display manager (the GUI program where you enter your user name and password, e.g. GDM, KDM, Lightdm, …) you use.

Comment: I managed to solve this by setting `LANG` at two different places, one for the console, and one for X: see my comments above for exactly what I did (but it was Mr. Chazelas who got my on the right `LANG` track). This solved both problems, including the compose key, but I won't pretend this is anything I understand. Maybe, without the specified encoding, the computer didn't even notice that the compose key was pressed?

Comment: @EmanuelBerg It probably did, but then transmitted the wrong character from the application. I admit I don't recognize the failure mode from your description. You're apparently using a UTF-8 locale; it would help to know how your machine is set up — distribution, desktop environment, display manager.

Comment: Oh, you still want it. Sure: Debian (sid), with GNOME remnants (e.g., Metacity), but I disabled gdm3 and instead autologin to the ttys and then onwards to X with `xinit` (so I run urxvt and Metacity in `.xinitrc`).

Comment: @EmanuelBerg Weird, `export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` in `.profile` should suffice then (it's what I do, except that I don't use Metacity).

Comment: Yes, `export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` in `.zprofile` works. It is better than the above solution as it is one fix (not two), and only in the user's directory (perhaps `LC_CTYPE` is less heavy-handed than `LANG` as well). As for the weirdness about it, I think bash loads some file, either by default or setup by me (i.e., run from some other file), either way, in that file, the locale is set. When I switched to zsh, this file was suddenly not run.